# Change body background based on number range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around with [simpleWeather.js](http://simpleweatherjs.com/) and I would like to change the body background based on the weather conditions. This plugin uses [Yahoo weather codes](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html#codes) to determine this. For this example, I want to set a background image for the ranges 0-10, 10-20 and another one for everything else.

I had no problems when dealing with a simpler condition (if less than 25 change background else if larger than 25 set another) but when I tried to add more if's and else's it stopped working. The plugin doesn't load and it's stuck on the loading image.

Can anyone help me out with this? [Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/desmondinyoface/pen/vdpPmr) im working on and this is my source:

```
 if(weather.code > 0 && weather.code < 10) {
    $('body').addClass('cloudy');
  } else if(weather.code > 10 && weather.code < 20) {
    $('body').addClass('stormy');
  }
  else {
    $('body').addclass('whatever');
  }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Define "stopped working", it looks fine, although I suspect you're not getting the expected behaviour when `weather.code` is exactly 10. Is that what you mean, or something else?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question. It's stuck on the loading image for me.

Comment: Any console errors? addClass is camelCase btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine! But you missed a capital letter.

In your last else you have addclass you have to use addClass

```
  if(weather.code > 0 && weather.code < 10) {
    $('body').addClass('cloudy');
  } else if(weather.code > 10 && weather.code < 20) {
    $('body').addClass('stormy');
  }
  else {
    $('body').addClass('whatever');
  }
```

This code works just fine

Comment: Crikey! It was that simple, changed it and now it works for me. Thanks

Comment: @ScreamQueen Perfect! Sometimes it's hard to spot little mistakes ;) I spotted it using the developer console you can see the error addclass is not a function. Also could you mark my answer as answer.

Answer (score 1):

can't reproduce your problem,but i guess the problem is the class;

maybe you should remove other class first and then add your class for weather;

```
    $('body').removeClass();
if(weather.code > 0 && weather.code < 10) {
    $('body').addClass('cloudy');
  } else if(weather.code > 10 && weather.code < 20) {
    $('body').addClass('stormy');
  }
  else {
    $('body').addClass('whatever');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems ok once you use correct case in addClass, but try this simpler code - you can repeat the ifs for every number you want to test

```
function getBg(code) {
  if (code<10) return "cloudy";
  if (code<20) return "stormy";
  return “whatever";
}
```

Then use

```
$('body').addClass(getBg(weather.code));
```